# Html Form Multiple Selectbox using SumoSelect, mark required fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms, performance, sumoselect.js

I am using [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/), a jquery Dropdown, for `<select>` fields in my html form. How can I mark them as required when submitting the form? Native `<select>` fields get a notice by chrome, Firefox, etc. can I replicate that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by using [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/):

```
$(SumoselectFieldSelector).rules("add",{
    required:true,
    messages:{
        required:"Field is required"
        }
})
```